# Comparing between $\sin^2 x $ and $(\sin x)^2 $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

1. $\sin^2 x  $
2. $(\sin x)^2 $

Yes, I know that these two are interchangeable.

But why must we change to the second form before we differentiate it?

What's the explanation behind this theory?

Comment: You don't have to but it allows you to see how the power rule applies.

Comment: People often jump too conclusion that the main function of $\sin^2x$ is $\sin x$ so for example they derive it like $\cos^2 x\cdot (\cos x)$ or something like that (I've witnessed something similar happen with $\sin^2 x$).Instead of deriving it like $((\sin x)^2)'=2(\sin x) \cos x$

Comment: "But why must we change to the second form before we differentiate it": we mustn't. Where did you see that ?

Comment: See [What is $\sin^2 x$ equal to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123424/what-is-sin2x-equal-to)

Comment: "What's the story behind this *theory*?  First of all, there is no theory behind the fact that, as a *convention*, mathematicians use $\sin^2x$ instead of $(\sin x)^2$ to denote "the square of the (sin x)."  Other than that please see E.Josephs answer, and also the answer given by @Mr.Xcoder.  Note that the same holds for using $\cos^n x = (\cos x)^n$,  and ditto for all the other trig functions.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2(x)$ is just a **notation** for $(\sin(x))^2$.

So no explanation to give, you usually write $\sin^2 x$ instead of $(\sin (x))^2$ just to avoid the confusion $\sin(x^2)\ne (\sin(x))^2$.

Using the form $(\sin(x))^2$ emphasizes that it is indeed a *power*, so maybe it is easier to see how to differentiate it.

Comment: $\sin(x)^2$ is ambiguous and should be banned.

Comment: Harsh. Just be careful.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: When I first encountered trigonometry in comprehensive school, I actually thought that $\sin^2(x)$ meant $\sin(\sin(x))$.

Answer (score 0):

The common notation is $\sin^2(x)$, just to avoid confusion, because $\sin(x)^2$ is ambiguous, and can either be interpreted as: 
$$\sin (x^2)$$ **or** $$(\sin x)^2$$

Comment: or $(\sin x)^2$

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mr.Xcoder, but would like to add why you 'have' to

> change to the second form before we differentiate it?

It is simply because it is easier to read while doing the calculation:
$\frac {d}{dx}[(\sin(x)^2] = 2\sin (x)\frac {d}{dx}[\sin(x)]=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Note: you don't 'have' to do this.